# Is there a way to set the size of a slurm script job array based on a value in the script itself?

Tags: bash, slurm

My scripts usually look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --array=0-10

myarray=($(seq 0 1 10))

echo ${myarray[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}
```

How can I make it that the `--array` parameter is set based on the size of `myarray`, assuming that `myarray` is an input from the user?

Comment: What does that mean? How is "an input from user" inputted??

Comment: I don't know how to answer that question without being tautological..An input from a user is inputted....by definition? This script is an example. `myarray` could be hardcoded, passed by CLI argument, etc...

Comment: I just don't understand your question. What does it mean for "--array parameter" to be "set"? How should it behave depending on `myarray` size? If `myarray` has more then 100 elements, then `--array` parameter should be "set"? What does it mean for a parameter to be "set"? It would be easier if you would show what should happen and when. You want to write `if ((${#myarray} > 100)); then set -- --array; fi`?

Comment: If `myarray` is length 11, then I want precisely 11 array tasks, preferably numbered 0 through 10, to be submitted to the queue. One would set `--array=0-10` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to set it with a command located in the script itself. Besides the `#SBATCH` comments, the script is indeed only interpreted when the job starts, and at that time, the `--array` parameter must be set already.

One option si to have the user simply set the `--array` parameter from the command line at submission time:

```
sbatch --array=0-10 submit_script.sh
```

or set the `SBATCH_ARRAY_INX` env variable, which is equivalent.

You can create a wrapper script or Bash function to create the proper submission command line from input provided by the user in any way they see fit.